# Epson advanced printer driver 4 failed to install common modules in Windows XP Embedded SP2

Tags: drivers, printer, windows-xp-embedded

I was trying to install Epson printer TM-T81's drivers in Windows xp embedded sp2 but an  error message is displayed during installation

> Failed to install common modules: Error code 1603. Setup will delete
>   the current installation. Fatal error during installation.

How to recover from this error?

Answer (score 0):

Did the device driver come with an install package?  If you check the .INF file for configuration settings, there may be something that is causing the driver to be installed incorrectly.

Seems as if an XML or XML schema could also be the cause of this issue, not to sure as I do not have access to your machine, but, that could be a cause of it.  I know this is not a definite answer, but, I cannot comment.